# Enforce function calls at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, named-parameters

Is there a way in C++ to enforce function calls in compile time in such a way that this call will be allowed:

```
obj.reset().setParam1(10).setParam2(20);
```

but this one will fail to compile:

```
obj.reset().setParam1(10);
```

I want to avoid setting all parameters in one function since there are too many to be set; so I prefer to use something similar to named parameters idiom.

EDIT: Alternative syntax could be:

```
obj.reset(setParam1(10), setParam2(20));
```

or

```
obj.reset(setParam1(10).setParam2(20));
```

Comment: I don't really think you can do anything with it.
With some template magic maybe you can achieve similar behaviour, but with different syntax. Can you tell me why you actually need it? Maybe we can find a solution with a smarter design. :P

Comment: @Melkon The goal is to force the class user to set ALL the required parameters without forcing him to use one setter function with a dozen of arguments.

Comment: Well, i don't exactly understand what's the point of that syntax then. I thought you want something like you have 5 parameters, but it's mandatory to define at least 2 of them. Actually chaining functions is slower, and way harder to read, compared to one function that set all parameter. You also can store all input parameter in a struct, and define a single function, which need that struct. Why this syntax is important?

Comment: Define a structure with all parameters and Set method with this structure as parameter. Remove single setParam methods.

Comment: @Melkon & Alex When a structure is used for initialization a user still can set some of it fields and leave the rest uninitialized.

Comment: Reset can give default value for everything, or you can check every time, when you want to use them if they are initialized, or not.

Comment: Read about [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I could do to provide both named parameters and enforce all of them being initialized is this.

```
template<typename T>
struct Setter
{
    Setter(const T &param) : ref(param) {}
    const T &ref;
};


typedef Setter<int> Param1;
typedef Setter<std::string> Param2;


struct CObj
{
    void reset(const Param1 &A, const Param2 &B) {
            setParam1(A.ref); setParam2(B.ref); }

    void setParam1(int i) { param1 = i; }
    void setParam2(const std::string &i) { param2 = i; }

    int param1;
    std::string param2;
};



int main()
{
    CObj o;
    o.reset(Param1(10), Param2("hehe"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the desired behaviour must be present at compile time, it needs to be implemented within the type system. To my understanding, this is impossible in C++ - the named parameters idiom relies on setter functions having the same return type (namely the type of the object which is called on), so calls to certain methods cannot be prevented.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you an example of doing that with the 2 parameters you provide, if you need more, it needs more work. If the requirement hierarchy between parameters get too complex, you may find it hard to structure your classes but here it goes:

```
class Obj {
    Obj2 setParam2(int v);
}

class Obj2: public Obj {
    Obj2 setParam1(int v);
}

int main() {
    Obj obj;
    obj.setParam2(10); // possible
    obj.setParam2(10).setParam1(20); // possible
    obj.setParam1(20); // not possible
    obj.setParam1(20).setParam2(10); // unfortunately not possible

    // Edit: one more limitation- consecutive calls are not possible, 
    // you must chain
    obj.setParam2(20);
    obj.setParam1(10); // problem
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but the type definition enforces a fixed sequence of setter calls.

Comment: Or multiple "fixed sequences of setter calls" if more parameters are needed and more classes are used. This concept is used by some libraries to provide a chainable API that is easy to use.

Comment: In my case obj.setParam2(10) is forbidden. One must call ALL the setters. The order is not important. I was thinking about making obj1-obj2-objn chain and then changing the reset functions to receive objn argument: obj.reset(setParam1(10).setParam(20)) but then how would obj reference get into setParam1() function? I'm a little confused.

Comment: You can define `reset()` with return type `Obj`. If you cannot find out how to implement this, let me know, I can help.

Comment: Oh wait, if all parameters must be set, this won't work for you. It just lets your restrict the order of chainable function calls.